# Access files on webserver from Android but lock them from browser

Tags: java, php, android, .htaccess

I'm trying to find the best method to access files (such as .jpg images) from a web server while effectively locking them from being opened in a browser. I want to lock the files with a POST key of some kind.

What's my best bet here? I was thinking .htaccess and then open my FTP using some PHP code, then calling this PHP file with some POST parameters.

Comment: I have not yet found the best option, thinking of going with my FTP and POST idea but I'm not sure if it is the best option.